# VPS apache config - Invalid command 'PassengerDefaultRuby' after adding latest passenger gem

Tags: apache-2.2, vps, phusion-passenger, ruby

used to have this list of rubies in my vps:

```
   ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ i686 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p374 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ i686 ]
```

today I installed a new app on this vps on `ruby 2.0`, so I added 2.0 to `rvm`:

```
   ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p374 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ i686 ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ i686 ]
```

installed `passenger` and `passenger-apache-module`, instructions says to add these lines:

```
   LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19
   PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby
```

to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and restart apache, after restart I got this **error**:

```
Syntax error on line 242 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'PassengerDefaultRuby', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

and one more **problem**, when I open my app at http://nccm.md I got:

```
Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

from `gem list` command I can see this gem is installed in ruby 2.0 environment, but the app looks for it in `usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global` and not in `ruby-2.0.0-p247@global`. Why is that? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

you need to have a default ruby assigned at root level, the other ones you'll set in `sites-enabled` configuration files. For example, in my `apache2.conf` file:

```
   LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19
   PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby
```

then in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite` that fires up the app that should work in `ruby-1.9.3` I'll add `PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby`:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xx.xx.xx:80>
  PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby
  ServerName mysite.md
  DocumentRoot /home/apps/myapp/public
  <Directory /home/apps/myapp>
     AllowOverride None
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

for the app that works with `ruby-2.0` no need to add `PassengerRuby` option as `ruby-2.0` is the default one now.

Also if you have other rvm passenger modules loaded in apache2.config file, like in my case I had:

```
#   LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.18/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
#   PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.18
#   PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby
```

you'll need to remove them or comment them as I did, as you'll load the ruby version in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite` config file.